# Allocating memory in native heap

Tags: android, jvm

I'm trying to consume memory from the native heap by using ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()

I can see in memory monitor that memory allocated in dalvik jvm heap instead of the native heap.

Has anybody encountered similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on Android, direct byte-buffers allocated from Java count towards the Dalvik heap: https://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2367